# CMake doesn't appear to be linking CppUnit

Tags: linker, cmake, cppunit, ctest

This may already be answered somewhere, so please point me in the right direction if so - I couldn't find anything that matched my specific problem when googling!

I've got some CppUnit tests that I'm trying to run.

My top-level CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
include_directories(
    ${CPPUNIT_INC}
)
link_directories(
    ${CPPUNIT_LIB}
)
```

Both of which are set correctly: I print the paths earlier in the CMakeLists.txt file, and they're correct.

In the subfolder, I have;

```
add_executable(test-lumberjack TestLumberjack.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
    test-lumberjack
    Lumberjack
    CppUnit
    ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
)
INSTALL(TARGETS test-lumberjack DESTINATION ${PROJECT_OUTPUT_TEST_DIR})
ADD_TEST(NAME test-lumberjack COMMAND "${PROJECT_OUTPUT_TEST_DIR}/test-lumberjack")
```

However, when I run the tests (either by running the file or using `ctest -V`), I see the <s>usual linker error</s> **EDIT: it's not a linker error, see answer below**

The library definitely exists, in the path set earlier in the top level CMakeLists.txt.

I'm stumped! I'm assuming there's something key that I'm totally missing, but I haven't a clue what it is. If you'd like more info, let me know and I'll add it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot: the CppUnit folder wasn't in my library path. Should've realised this when it was crashing at runtime, not during compilation... Doh!